# How to parse JSON data on Android?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am new at all this android programming and I would like to know how to parse data from this website here: http://ec2-54-213-155-95.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/notices.php ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have keys from `0` to `17`. So total 18 keys. You can try getting the values in an string array.

```
String [] str = new String[18];
for ( int i = 0; i < 18; i++ ){
    str[i] = json.getString(String.valueOf(i)); // Keys are string

}
```

Here `json` is the JSON object that you are receiving.

Comment: ok but this is linked to a facebook group page. so everytime there's a new post, there will be a new key

Comment: You might then need to have a count of how many keys are there and accordingly use the above.

Comment: Ok and from the code that you just wrote, how can I parse it?

Comment: See http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#length%28%29 You can use `.length` function to get the number of keys. Replace `18` with the return value of the `length()` function. Also regarding you comment, its not clear to me what do you want to parse ? You got string values corresponding to the keys. They are stored in the form of array of strings. You can access each string by `str[indexValue]` . I didn't get you.

Comment: I want to display the data as a textview or listview, by the way thanks for taking the time of doing all this !!

Comment: Create a listView. Copy the data into an ArrayList. ( or instead of taking the data in an String [] array, you can directly insert to ArrayList) and set the cursor in the list adapter to the list. If all this didn't make sense, then you need to check out a basaic tutorial which teaches you how to make a ListView.

Comment: Fir TextView, if you want to set all the data in one TextView, then its easy. Otherwise instead of making `n`n number of TextView's you can make a List. Ask a different questions if you face some problem with it. :)